# conf file for logstash database not sqlite

Tags: database, logstash

can logstash read data from a database stored in a server and not a sqlite db file?

If yes, how should I edit the "input" section of the conf file for logstash?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't currently because there are no inputs for SQL servers other than sqlite.  If you want, you can write your own input plugin for any SQL server.

There is a tutorial here:
http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/extending/